# Javascript and Java make same validation

Tags: java, javascript, regex, validation, grails

This is just something I'm wondering about now that I've come to implement it.

Is there a way to make validation (rules on password/usernames) in Javascript and Java equivalent other than using the same regular expressions on both sides?

I could use regex, but I'd rather use something more high-level. I remember using JQuery to do that once and will be taking another look again soon. Of course, if I go down that road, the validation on the server side will be implemented differently. As long as the validation on the server side is correct, this isn't really a problem, but it would be nice to know I have the exact same set of rules on both sides.

Any suggestions?

---

Edit:

I seem to remember Grails has some nice support for validation. I am not using Grails but I am using Groovy. Is there some dependency I could use to get the same sort of thing outside of Grails?

Comment: validation require backend process. do u want to achieve validation of username and password without any backend server side code ?

Comment: No, obviously back-end validation takes priority. I just wanted to know whether someone knows of a way to get the same rules on both ends using something easier to work with than regex. Regex is doable but what can I say, I'm lazy :P

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the usual way to go is to "mirror" client-side validation on the server-side--for example, presence validation on the client and non-nullable fields in your model. Or the same regular expression written on both ends. There isn't really an abstraction to make the rules in one place in the manner you want.

However, I can think of a couple of options that approximate what you want.

- Pass the regular expression to the client in a hidden input field and simply write JavaScript to use it to perform pattern matching on your username and password fields.
- Use a thicker framework like JavaServer Faces. It generates JavaScript and handles validation on the server side only, but it is an abstraction where you only have to write the code once. I have no numbers to back this up, but I sense that technology has a lost a lot of steam over the years. Grails and Play are more modern and popular examples of the same idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for passing the regex to Javascript... I think I would have hard coded if I were going down that path. Still, I'm thinking I'll try using some available tools on the front end, and then do the same or more validation on the server side.

Comment: I had used jQuery a while back (like 2 years ago) to do this sort of thing, and I do remember not having to use regular expressions. That's what I was referring to. Still have to look into this though as I have forgotten what I did exactly.

Answer (score -1):

It is best to place all your validation rules at your server side, using java. Do not forget that this can get complex, or often require data from your server side e.g. unique usernames. <strike>Then you can have your js use ajax to call specific services of your server side, that call the validation rules on whatever has been entered and output any notifications on the form.</strike>

If your validation rules are minor like required fields, then just place it on js and have non nullable fields at your persistence layer.

**EDIT - COMMENTS**

*The intention of this answer was to indicate that validations should exist in the back end, to always ensure the data processed is correct whether validated in the front end or not. In the back end it's possible to access data that is not available in the front end and also have the complexity in one place, that will process the data (eg store it) and possibly reuse the logic (eg api library used elsewhere).*

*This is also more relevant nowadays that usually the back ends are on a completely separate layer/deployment/microservices providing APIs.*

*In the front end validations can be mirrored, but usually we only add the simple ones. The main reasons for validating in the front end are to save network calls and back end processing (eg no need to make a call to check password length or to send bad data that will fail etc) and provide better user experience (eg no reason to let user fill a form with 20 fields and wait for a long message from server with errors on each etc).
Logic should be written once and be able to easily update in one place.*

Comment: Is it really best practice to put all your validation rules on the server side? I would like to avoid unnecessary requests if possible, so I don't think having validation on the front end is a bad idea. Of course, that doesn't substitute back-end validation.

Comment: @justin I would say that the best practice in this case is to validate in both, client and server. Client because the user get's a faster feedback, and server because the user can disable JavaScript in the browser. But says that something is "best practice" is just a opinion.

Comment: Ok thanks Sergio. I had asked this question with a "just in case" mindset. As in, I guess "no - just do validation on both ends and make sure you hit the same rules" is the answer".

Comment: If you put all your validation on the backend then you put a large strain on AJAX requests to your backend to verify user inputs which is not user friendly as performance suffers here on the user waiting for a response from the backend to be satisfied they have entered a valid input. Copying what others have said the front end and backend should mirror the basic validation, with the backend being a catch all scenario for anything that should ultimately be denied and has managed to bypass the initial client side validation.

Comment: @bmjrowe it's been a long time and should probably edit this answer to make it more precise and clear. I agree and that was mainly the intention.